# Conflict on JS files after combining Material Design Lite and Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, material-design-lite

I've combined Material Design Lite and Bootstrap 4 to make this site responsive: http://virtualvizcaya.org/3d-documentation2.html

I've found a bug when loading iframes (a html document in the same domain): the iframe loads twice. I noticed that when I remove the material.min.js that came with the Material Design Lite template, the iframe loads only once but the sidenav doesn't work (which it's why I'm using this template).

Could anyone suggest any solutions, please!!!

Comment: There are likely to be multiple css and js conflicts between MDL and Bootstrap. You might look into something like [Material Design for Bootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/material-design-for-bootstrap/) if you are intent on a design that combines the two.

Comment: @benvc I wish I could but SideNav is a Pro feature I can't afford, thanks for your input!